# Why are are integrals of functions in coordinates on manifolds not invariant under coordinate transformations?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I'm reading the book *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*. And there is a question that confuse me on page 202.[image: The place marked green]

Can anyone tell me why it would change under coordinate transformations graphically? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** Consider the coordinate transformation $$f : (x^1, \ldots, x^n) \mapsto (\lambda x^1, \ldots, \lambda x^n) ,$$ where $\lambda > 0$. What is $\operatorname{Vol}(f(C))$?

Comment: @ Travis   For example,$n=1$, $C=[0,1]$, $\int_{0}^{1}{1} d{x}=1$. If $y=2x$, then $\int_{0}^{1}{1} d{x}=\int_{0}^{2}{1/2} d{y}=1$, so I get $\int_{C}f dV$ is invariant.

Comment: @Penson You've transformed what the cited text calls $dV$, whereas in writing $\int_C f \,dV = \operatorname{Vol}(C)$ the text calls for no such transformation, that is, $dV$ is to be interpreted here as $dx^1 \cdots dx^n$ for any coordinate system $(x^a)$. The point is that we *do* have to transform $dV$ as well for the integral to be invariant. From this point of view, we need to integrate (in your example) the $1$-form $dx$, not the function $1$.

Comment: Similarly, on a general $n$-manifold, we do not integrate functions (well, except when $n = 0$), we can only integrate $n$-forms as (at least in the scope of this discussion) these are the only objects that transform in a way such that the resulting integral value is independent of the choice of coordinate chart.

Comment: @ Travis Sorry, I don't understand your word "The point is that we do have to transform dV as well for the integral to be invariant. From this point of view, we need to integrate (in your example) the 1-form dx, not the function 1",can you say it more clear?

Comment: Perhaps a geometrically clearer way to see what's going on is this: Suppose $S$ is some open subset of $M$, small enough that it fits inside a coordinate chart $(U, \phi)$. One could attempt to define the volume of $S$ as $\int_{\phi(S)} dx^1 \cdots dx^n$, but the value of this integral is going to depend on the chart we chose, so it's not 'invariant'. The problem isn't that $f$ depends on the choice of chart (indeed, it doesn't), the problem is that the coordinate $x^a$ and hence the differentials $dx^a$ and hence volume $dx^1 \cdots dx^n$ depend on the chart.

Comment: @ Travis  Thank you. I get it.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad you found it helpful.

Comment: @ Travis I would like to ask you further about you comment. So you defined the volume of S to be $\int_{\phi (S)} 1 dx^1 \cdots dx^n$ but, however, it would be dependent on the choice of chart in the way that if we choose another chart, say $(V, \psi, (y^i) )$, then we don’t necessarily have $\int_{\phi (S)} 1 dx^1 \cdots dx^n= \int_{\psi (S)} 1 dy^1 \cdots dy^n$. So that’s not coordinate-independent. Is this what you meant?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the point---thus defining volume to be $\int_{\phi(S)} 1 \,dx^1 \cdots dx^n$ is not a good definition, since it depends on the choice of coordinates, but in differential geometry we're (mostly) interested in quantities that are independence of that choice.